# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryMaster':

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryMaster': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject

```
<bean id="sessionFactoryMaster"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMaster" />
<property name="packagesToScan">
    <list>
        <value>com.XXXXX.common.hibernate.entities</value>
    </list>
</property>

<property name="entityInterceptor" ref="auditInterceptor" />
</bean>


<bean id="auditTrailsDaoImpl" class="com.XXXXX.domain.dao.impl.AuditTrailsDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryMaster" />
</bean>

<bean id="auditInterceptor"
    class="com.XXXXX.interceptors.AuditInterceptor" lazy-init="true"  >
    <property name="auditTrailsDao" ref="auditTrailsDaoImpl" />

</bean>
```

Any idea on the cause of the error and solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is a circular dependency in your configuration. Your sessionFactoryMaster requires an auditInterceptor object which requires a auditTrailsDao.The auditTrailsDao in turn requires  the sessionFactoryMaster bean which is currently in creation.

Consider making your auditTrailsDao / auditInterceptor dependent on dataSource instead. You can also make your auditTrailsDao lookup the sessionFactory as a work around

```
public class AuditTrailsDao{

   public void saveTrail(AuditTrail auditTrail){
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = lookupSessionFactory();
        //save trail
   }
}
```

You can lookup session factory by making your bean aware of the ApplicationContext by implementing ApplicationContextAware and the using getBean method to get reference to SessionFactory. This is not recommended as it ties up your application to Spring.

However there is a mechanism to use the ServiceLocatorFactoryBean to decouple your application from Spring APIs but still allowing your component to lookup a dependency

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.html